# script expire when inserting bulk record

Tags: php, centos

I'm facing problem when I'm inserting bulk record from one table to another

so process is 
i have a `csv` that has bulk records i have used infile for that , that is working fine . Now i have to insert that records to another table with certain conditions on many field .

But while inserting records to the table script expire in `30 sec` approx .
below is what i already set .

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

and running `phpinfo()` shows

```
Directive           Local Value   Master Value

max_execution_time  0             60

max_file_uploads    20            20

PHP Version     5.3.3 

 CentOS 6.7 install
```

Thanks in advance for your help .

Comment: Please provide us with the part of your script which deals with time management. In which line does your script calls `set_time_limit()` ?

Comment: it is in the top . and i just researched that i have to edit this php.ini file "/etc/php.ini" but when i try doing that , it says 550 php.ini: Permission denied . please guide .

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to your php.ini file, then correct its permission and edit it accordingly.

You can also create an empty php.ini in your public_html (root directory) and just add a line for maximum execution time.

But another way to handle maximum execution time is that, you can add to the default PHP timer using `set_time_limit()`, but not definitely in the very first line. It adds to the timer, it does not set a default value as does php.ini, also as PHP Documentation says, you cannot use in if php is run in safe_mode.

It is better, if after all you do not have access to php configuration, to handle your script using `set_time_limit()`. You can make a time utility manager for such purpose. Use `set_time_limit()` in the heart of your script when you think time is running out. For instance:

```
while(true)
{
  if(get_time_of_my_script() == 25) // assuming php.ini's limit is 30 seconds
  {
    set_time_limit(20); // add 20 more seconds
  }
}

function get_time_of_my_script()
{
   // write something that calculates your execution time from the 
   //  very first line till the invocation
   // of the function
}
```

Though you should bear in mind that:

- All timing settings of php is limited to the PHP internally. If you execute a `system()` call then it is not under PHP's control until it returns something. Therefore, if you are dealing with DB, make sure about timing of DB engine.
- Other environmental settings such as Apache/IIS timing settings would normally limit PHP after a certain length of time (though their default is 300 seconds which is adequate probably for you).

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer .  php safe mode is off , execution time for my script is approx 1 hrs or more :( . as there are thousands of records and each record need to be matched before inserting .

Comment: Have you tried running your script through CLI? It might work indeed

Comment: ok may i know the difference b/w cli and fast cli  as i searched over net , and it has been solved already .